# adding dynamically input box but it should stop base on the criteria,,,

Tags: javascript, jquery

elow is the code i am using i am able to add new input box wen i click but it should stop adding based on the user input like no. of user-entered as 4 based on that add input box should stop

in below example:-$bookcount is user input field which comes from html input box

```
var i = 1;
 
 if(i>$(bookcount))
 {
    $('#add').click(function()
    {
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="title[]" </td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');

 }});

$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
    $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
});

$('#submit').click(function(){      
    $.ajax({
        url:"name.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
        success:function(data)
**strong text**     {
            alert(data);
            $('#add_name')[0].reset();
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: `$(bookcount)` gives you a jquery object - perhaps you meant `if (i > ($(bookcount).val() * 1)) ...`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(i < $(bookcount).val())` assuming you have a `var bookcount = $('#bookcount-input'); `

Comment: It's working thank you soo much @freedomn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues to note:

- Assuming `bookcount` is found from `$("#bookcount")` then you'll need to get the `.val()` and convert it to a number (as "10"<"2")
- Check against bookcount value *inside* the click event:

```
var i = 1;
var bookcount = $("#bookcount");
 
$('#add').click(function() {
    if (i>(bookcount.val()*1)) {
        // do nothing
        return false; 
    }

    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr....
```

- as you also have a remove function, don't forget to reduce `i` when removing

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
    --i;
```

(in this case, I recommend something other than `i`, eg `rowCount`).

---

You can also do away with `i` (`rowCount`) by querying how many rows have been created dynamically:

```
var bookcountinput = $("#bookcount");

$('#add').click(function() {
    var rows = $("#dynamic_field tr").length;
    if (rows > bookcountinput.val()*1) 
        return;

    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr....    
});
```

Comment: Thank you bro for the response but its not working for me. its allowing n no. of time to add new fields.. you can see i add my UI screen above. its no. of adults is 2 but its not stoping me add pax till 2 only.

Comment: Yes, you might need some minor tweak to get exactly how you want it, eg use `rows >= bookcountlimit` if you have fixed first row and the limit is how many extra rows to add.  Glad you got it sorted.